Error Ansible for backup script on Windows Server with SCP
I'm writing a script for an incremental backup of a Windows server to a Linux server via SCP with Ansible, I'm having difficulties connecting to the SCP, as it is incorrectly identifying the directory for backup. Sorry about my English.
My Script:
---                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 - name: Backup incremental de servidor Windows para Linux
   hosts: srv-ror
   tasks:
     - name: Obter a lista de arquivos modificados nas últimas 24 horas
       win_shell: |
         $now = Get-Date
         $yesterday = $now.AddDays(-1)
         Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop" -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $yesterday } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
       register: modified_files
  
     - name: Criar um arquivo com a lista de arquivos modificados
       win_shell: |
         $modified_files = @(
           {% for file in modified_files.stdout_lines %}
           "{{ file }}"
           {% endfor %}
         )
         $modified_files | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt -Encoding utf8
  
     - name: Transferir arquivos modificados para o servidor Linux via SCP (CMD)
       win_shell: |
         @echo off
         setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
         for /f "delims=" %a in (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt) do (scp %a root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror/)
        args:
         executable: cmd

When i run only the part:
for /f "delims=" %a in (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt) do (scp %a root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror/)

on CMD it gives me the following error
ssh: Could not resolve hostname \302\264\342\225\227\342\224\220c: No such host is known.

Error
How can i remove the byte (BOM)

There is no batch file here. You have a question about one of the three lines you are running in the win_shell cmd.exe; i.e. for /f "delims=" %a in (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt) do (scp %a root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror/). If it was a batch file that command should have been For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt") Do "P:\athTo\scp.exe" "%%~G" root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror.

You could probably fix your Unicode BOM issue by using the Type command instead, For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %G In ('Type "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt"') Do "P:\athTo\scp.exe" "%~G" root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror.

So, if that really was a batch file, rather than individual lines, run in sequence, within cmd.exe, that would change to For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\modified_files.txt"') Do "P:\athTo\scp.exe" "%%~G" root@192.168.0.251:/root/srv-ror. Because in a batch file the percent character is 'special', so requires escaping, (with another percent character). It even tells you that in the first few lines of the built in help for the for command you are using. Open a cmd.exe window, type for /?, and press the [ENTER] key to see that help information.
